# proper way to return monotouch asynchronous calls

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, xamarin.ios

Lets say i have an asynchoronous call in my monotouch project like this

```
context.getNameCompleted += HandleContextgetNameCompleted;
context.getNameAsync();

void HandleContextgetNameCompleted(object sender, getNameCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        string name = args.Result;
    }
```

Now how do I get another asynchronous method running that relies on the completion of the first without getting the program to crash. So for instance my second call might be

```
context.getAgeCompleted += HandleContextgetAgeCompleted;
context.getAgeAsync();

void HandlegetAgeCompleted(object sender, getAgeCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        string age = args.Result;
    }
```

the second method can only return a value once we return the "name" from the first person. Please provide in reasons and/or examples of how to properly use this method or any alternate solution.As usual your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fire the 2nd request when you handle the completion of the first one.

```
void HandleContextgetNameCompleted(object sender, getNameCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        string name = args.Result;

        context.getAgeCompleted += HandleContextgetAgeCompleted;
        context.getAgeAsync();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. My actual application consists of several asynchronous calls. I previously only nested the last request in the one before it. That didnt help since there were other requests that the last 2 depended on to occur before. Once I organized them sequentially, it all came together. Thank again.